# Render error black areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

here when i'am render this project it gives me these annoying black squares don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue guys it was some edges and faces i couldn't see, i try to slowly find them and fixed that, i will leave this here if anyone face that too maybe helpful.